# PowerShell: How to get two character strings into a single line in an output file

Tags: powershell

I want a line in an output file to look like

Installed_VCS_Version =  x.x.x.x (version input from PS command)

I have tried doing this via the following commands

```
New-Item FileVersion3.txt
Set-Content FileVersion3.txt 'Installed File Version = '
Add-Content FileVersion3.txt (Get-Command 'C:\Users\Downloads\<x>.dll').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

But this appends the file version onto a new line, whereas I want it on the same line.

I have tried to pipe the two streams via the Set Content command but I can't get it to work.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? Sorry if the question is very basic but I am a beginner at PowerShell. I have looked up a PS on-line Tutorial but this issue is not referenced

Comment: Sorry the commands appear garbled in the above description. here they are again

Comment: New-Item FileVersion3.txt

Set-Content FileVersion3.txt 'Installed File Version = '

Add-Content FileVersion3.txt (Get-Command 'C:\Users\lafarnum\Downloads\aniteloggingclientapi.dll').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

Comment: `Set-Content ... -NoNewLine`

Comment: HI Juts to add I have also tried this with the -NoNewline option but it does not work

When I try this
PS Set-Content FileVersion7.txt 'Installed File Version = '
PS Add-Content -NoNewline FileVersion7.txt (Get-Command 'C:\Users\lafarnum\Downloads\aniteloggingclientapi.dll').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

Comment: My file shows
Installed File Version = 

So it has not added the file version returned from the Get-Command cmdlet

But if I input

Set-Content FileVersion7.txt 'Installed File Version = '
 Add-Content FileVersion7.txt (Get-Command 'C:\Users\lafarnum\Downloads\aniteloggingclientapi.dll').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion

Then the output file looks like this

Comment: Installed File Version = 
1.12.0.4

Comment: Sorry I meant it looks like this

Installed File Version = 
1.12.0.4

Comment: Sorry I meant it looks lime 
Installed File Version = 
1.12.0.4

Comment: I meant that there is a line between the Installed File Version =  and the 1.12.0.4
Installed File Version = 

1.12.0.4

Comment: Please can you stop writing code and results in comments as these are not suitable for formatting. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68770829/edit) your question and put the important info there as [Formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new file first, `Set-Content` will do that for you.

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
$v = (Get-Command 'C:\Users\Downloads\<x>.dll').FileVersionInfo.FileVersion
Set-Content -Path 'FileVersion3.txt' -Value "Installed File Version = $v"
```

Comment: Many thanks Theo for your input. I had implemented another solution but it was overly long and convoluted - yours is much more simple and effective.